# Join 2 fields from the same table in a row

Tags: mysql

i have this:

```
id     Level      module        permissions
------------------------------------------------
15    level 15    module 1    edit, add, delete
15    level 15    module 2    add, report
```

I want to have the result like this one:

```
id     Level      module        permissions        module      permissions 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
15    level 15    module 1    edit, add, delete   module 2     add, report
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, level, 
       'module 1' as module1, max(case when module = 'module 1' then permissions end) as permissions1,
       'module 2' as module2, max(case when module = 'module 2' then permissions end) as permissions2
from your_table
group by id, level
```

Comment: Here's a working fiddle to prove that it works cool http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e4b0/1

Comment: thanks for answer, but i forgot to say if i have modules dynamic, how can i do that, i mean more columns with more modules but i don't know how many modules i'm gonna have